# how to check if a size_t pointer is NULL? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, null

If I have these lines of code in C:

```
size_t num = 10;
size_t *pointer = &num;
```

The below check seems working, but I want to make sure I'm doing it right:

```
if (pointer != NULL)
    printf("pointer is not NULL \n");
else
    printf("pointer is NULL \n");
```

Comment: You are coding correctly. Notice that the address of any variable is always non null.

Comment: Worth noting: I recommend always putting constants on the left side of a comparison, i.e.: "if ( NULL != pointer )" because it avoids the possibility that you will accidentally write "if ( pointer = NULL )" which should generate a warning, but will not generate an error, and the odds that you will ignore or miss a warning are greater than zero.

Comment: @Irisshpunk: That's controversial advice. Many people (myself included) find [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) ugly and counterintuitive.

Comment: @KeithThompson I can understand that, readability and intuition are important and have to be tailored to the people reading your code. I like Yoda conditions because, like curly braces, they make me feel safe :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is a variable which points to address/memory location of another variable.

```
size_t num = 10;
```

According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), size_t is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bit. So *num* variable holds a value of 10.

```
size_t *pointer = &num;
```

A pointer named '*pointer*' is declared and it points to the address of variable '*num*' (ampersand (&) operator gives the address/memory location of the variable).

Since the pointer points to a value ,the pointer value is not NULL, so the output will be

```
pointer is not NULL
```

And to explain this,

**Null pointer**-If a pointer doesn't points to anywhere ,it is said to be a Null pointer

Comment: The pointer points to an object, not to a value. Void pointers are irrelevant to this question; the only pointer type used is `size_t*`.

Comment: Added just for the knowledge.

Comment: Why? `void*` has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

The C FAQ has a section dedicated to null pointers: http://c-faq.com/null/

This tells you that:

> According to the language definition, an "integral constant expression with the value 0'' in a pointer context is converted into a null pointer at compile time. That is, in an initialization, assignment, or comparison when one side is a variable or expression of pointer type, the compiler can tell that a constant 0 on the other side requests a null pointer, and generate the correctly-typed null pointer value.

So you test for null pointer like so:

```
if (pointer != 0)
```

Or more concisely:

```
if (pointer)
```

As for the `NULL` macro, again quoting from the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html):

> The preprocessor macro NULL is defined (by several headers, including `stdio.h` and `stddef.h`) as a null pointer constant, typically `0` or `((void *)0)`.

Comment: "As for the use of `NULL`, that depends on your definition of that macro." No, it doesn't. `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>`, and in several other standard headers, as an implementation-defined null pointer constant. It is absolutely required by the C standard. `if (pointer != NULL` is just as reliable as `if (pointer != 0)`, and is clearer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, unless it has been redefined. ;-) Not likely. I'll clean up.